# How and where to place .lower() in code with multiple conditions?

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a (simple) function. Based on user input (name and month) the function searches in the df. The code sums op the amount of money spent in that shop in the specified month.

Names in the df are written sometimes with capital, sometimes not. So I want all names extracted from df to be lowercase as well as all user input.

Making the name input lowercase is no problem. But how / where do I write .lower in the code with multiple conditions?

So my question is: how do I place `.lower` around the `.str.contains(naam)` part?

(code below works well when part of name is typed with Capital letters in the right spot).

```
def euro_month():

    name = input('What shop are you looking for: ')
    name = (name.lower())
    month = input('Give the month number, 1 - 12: ')

    df = df_2019.loc[((df_2019['Name'].str.contains(name)))&(df_2019['Month'] == int(month))]

    bedrag = round(df['Bedrag'].sum(),2)

    print('We spent in shop', name, 'in month ', str(maand), ' 2019', bedrag, ' Euro's.' )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pandas str.contains() has an argument to make the search not case sensitive https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html

in your code:

```
df = df_2019.loc[((df_2019['Name'].str.contains(name, case=False)))&(df_2019['Month'] == int(month))]
```

or instead you can use str.lower() https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.lower.html

```
df = df_2019.loc[((df_2019['Name'].str.lower().str.contains(name, case=False)))&(df_2019['Month'] == int(month))]
```

Comment: Wow, oke, thanks! Obviously I didn't read long enough in the documentation. Many thanks for your really fast answer!

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
df = df_2019.loc[((df_2019['Name'].str.lower().str.contains(name))) & (df_2019['Month'] == int(month))]
```

You can simply call `.lower` and then call `.str.contains`